# How to mount the second disk as /dev/md3 in linux server?

Tags: linux, mount, partition

At the moment when I type `lsblk -o NAME,SIZE,FSTYPE,TYPE,MOUNTPOINT` I get the following output:

```
NAME     SIZE FSTYPE            TYPE  MOUNTPOINT
sda      3.7T                   disk
├─sda1     1M                   part
├─sda2   512M swap              part  [SWAP]
├─sda3   3.6T linux_raid_member part
│ └─md2  3.6T ext4              raid1 /data
├─sda4  19.5G linux_raid_member part
│ └─md1 19.5G ext4              raid1 /
└─sda5   300M linux_raid_member part
  └─md0  299M ext4              raid1 /boot
sdb      3.7T                   disk
├─sdb1     1M                   part
├─sdb2   512M swap              part  [SWAP]
├─sdb3   3.6T linux_raid_member part
│ └─md2  3.6T ext4              raid1 /data
├─sdb4  19.5G linux_raid_member part
│ └─md1 19.5G ext4              raid1 /
└─sdb5   300M linux_raid_member part
  └─md0  299M ext4              raid1 /boot
```

When I type `df -h` I get

```
Filesystem      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
devtmpfs         16G     0   16G   0% /dev
tmpfs            16G     0   16G   0% /dev/shm
tmpfs            16G   65M   16G   1% /run
tmpfs            16G     0   16G   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
/dev/md1         20G  2.4G   16G  13% /
/dev/md0        282M  121M  143M  46% /boot
/dev/md2        3.6T  1.2G  3.4T   1% /data
tmpfs           3.2G     0  3.2G   0% /run/user/0
tmpfs           3.2G     0  3.2G   0% /run/user/48
```

I have only 1 volume with 3.4T and my goal is to have another volume /dev/md3 and to be mounted to /data2 and to be 3.4T as well, can you help me out to achieve it?

If additional information is required I can provide it.

Comment: Your question does not really follow. Are you aware MD* refer to RAID block devices, not disks? You either need more disk to create an md3 or you need to degrade an existing raid and misuse the freed up resource as another degraded array (not a good idea)

Comment: @davidgo Thank you for the answer. At the moment I have two disks on the server and instead of 8TB I see only 4TB in the file system, so I want to have two MD blocks - 4TB each and use all the space on the server. This is the first time I am facing this so, I am sorry if the question is incorrect.

Comment: Your md3 is a RAID 1 of size 3.6TB consisting of two partitions (sda3 and sdb3), thus you don't have a spare 4TB disk left over.

Comment: Okay, so in other words I need to reinstall the server so I can make two block of 4TB each

Comment: If its practical to reinstall, do so. It is possible to reconfigure without a reinstall, but doing so is fraught with risks and limitations that are probably not worthwhile at your skill level.

Comment: @davidgo I will try to reinstall and see if I can have `/dev/md2        3.6T  1.2G  3.4T   1% /data` and `/dev/md3        3.6T  1.2G  3.4T   1% /data2`

Comment: Stop using /dev/mdX - /dev/mdX is for RAID devices and you don't want to use RAID. Either use the underlying /dev/sdXY partitions directly or use LVM. (LVM is more complex but provides great flexibility for manipulating data at the block level).

Comment: To use /dev/mdX devices for 8tb of storage you would need to create degraded RAID arrays - bringing all the disadvantages with none of the advantages. That said, do you have a robust backup system for when one of your drives inevitably dies?

Comment: @davidgo No I think I don't have backup system, from what I read to have a backup system I have to spare 4TB so 1 disk can mirror the other disk in case it dies, this is correct, right? And thank you for the suggestion, I will no longer user MD* I will research what is LMV and how to use it

Comment: @Emmanuel-Ab  It would be foolhardy to do any of the kinds of disk operations you are looking at without a backup of your data.  I'm a seasoned expert and have done a lot of disk manipulation, and I wouldn't attempt one without a backup.

Comment: @davidgo I wasn't aware that I might have a problem with the disks (eventually) I thought that the chance of a disk to get corrupted or to die is close to none. Thank you, I might reconsider using one disk to be mirror of the another, just to have backup of the data.

Comment: Hard disks are by far the most likely part of your system to fail. They have an expected lifespan of about 5 years and seasoned techs consider them consumables. That is why RAID exists. Worse, they are so unreliable that RAID5 is dead because the chances of 2 large disks failing about the same time is very high.

Comment: Also, the disk operations I was talking about were those to reconfigure your current disks - although absolutely in a business environment storage servers need both RAID and a rotated backup system or equivalent.

Comment: @davidgo Thank you very much! I've decided to reinstall it and set RAID1 just to have a backup of my files, now that I know it is more likely one of my disks to die sooner rather than later.

Comment: You already have RAID1

Answer (score 0):

If I do understand your setup corrrect, you partitionend `sda` and `sdb` and created then the mdadm raids on top of these partitions.

The way to move off of this situation could be as follows:

- remove `sda3` from the raid using `mdadm`.
- update the partition table type entry in `sda3` to be a file system type (e.g. `83` for `Linux`)
- format `sda3` with your preferred file system.
- mount `sda3` to a new mount-point (e.g. `/data2`)
- copy all data from `/data/` to the new mount-point (e.g `/data2`)

---

- stop the raid for `md2` using `mdadm`.
- update partition table type of `sdb3`.
- format `sdb3` with your preferred file system.
- update mount point for `sda2` to be `/data`
- unmount `/data2` and mount `sda2` at `/data`
- mount `/dev/sdb3` to `/data2`